# Celery worker keeps creating new SQS queue

Tags: django, celery, amazon-ecs, amazon-sqs, kombu

I'm using Django with Celery and attempting to deploy Celery using SQS and ECS. These are my celery-related Django settings:

```py
CELERY_BROKER_URL = "sqs://"                                                                                        
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ["application/json"]
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = "json"
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = "json"
CELERY_IMPORTS = "app.tasks"
CELERY_BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {"region": "us-west-2"}
CELERY_TASK_DEFAULT_QUEUE = "staging.fifo"
```

My celery worker ECS task definition gives it full IAM access to SQS. But every time I start my celery worker ECS container, instead of using my existing SQS queue, "staging.fifo," the worker seems to create a new queue in SQS called "celery." Why is it creating this new queue instead of using the queue that I specified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized in my `celery.py` file, I had

```py
app.config_from_object("django.conf:settings")
```

Since I was not setting the namespace, all my `CELERY_` configuration variables were being ignored. I changed this to:

```py
app.config_from_object("django.conf:settings", namespace="CELERY")
```

and now it uses my queue! See the Celery with Django [docs](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html#using-celery-with-django) for more info.